# PHP MySQL Category Tree Parent Level ID

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree, categories

I'm creating a multi-level category with PHP/MySQL. I've listing my category items via ajax, but I can't get top levels by ID.

MySQL Table

```
ID   upCID   category

1      0     Electronics
2      1     Computers
3      1     Camera & Photo
5      2     Laptops
6      2     Desktop
7      6     Keyboard & Mouse
8      6     Processors
9      6     Memory
10     6     Storage
11     8     Fans & Cooling
12     8     Thermal Compounds
```

Listing:

> Electronics > Computers > Desktop > Processors > Thermal Compounds

I want to call my top-level IDs like;

**Thermal Compounds** root level is "**Electronics**"

or

**Thermal Compounds** 3th top-level is "**Desktop**"

Normally queries easily calling my top categories but I can't get specific levels by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible when you are using PL SQL